# React Native: Can't see console.logs when I run application from XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm struggling to get my code working with `react-native run-ios`. The native code is pulling some old cached version of the javascript bundle, and I can't seem to clear that to save my life.

When I run the application from XCode however, the application runs just fine. Awesome!

The only problem is that when I run my application through XCode, I can't seem to access the javascript logs. I've tried `react-native log-ios` but that doesn't seem to show my logs. I've tried "Enabling debugging in Chrome" from the simulator menu, but this option isn't available to me when I run the app from XCode.

Does anybody have any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Comment: Same here. but it says `NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.`. idk what log(1) is.

Comment: see my answer in another similar post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884984/4049216)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Option #1

`console.log` works. By default on iOS, it logs to the debug pane inside Xcode. If you select the "Debug in Chrome" or "Debug in Safari" options from the rage shake menu `(⌘+^+Z)`, it will log to the browser's console instead.

### Option #2

As of React Native 0.29 you'll be able to simply run the following to see logs on the command line:

```sh
react-native log-ios
react-native log-android
```

### Option #3

1. <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd>  + <kbd>D</kbd> to bring up the debug menu
2. Set "Debug in Safari" turned off, and some messages would be printed to the output message, but not console messages. However, one of the log message says:

   > **DEV** === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON"

   This was because I had previously bundled my project for testing on a real device with the command:

   ```
   react-native bundle --minify
   ```

   This bundled without "dev-mode" on. To allow dev messages, include the `--dev` flag:

   react-native bundle --dev

   And `console.log` messages are back! If you aren't bundling for a real device, don't forget to re-point `jsCodeLocation` in `AppDelegate.m` to localhost (I did!).

Comment: In the question, I mentioned that I tried both of these and neither seem to be working for me.

Comment: By the way, I'm on react-native 0.29.2

Comment: @Annie Gupta when I run code from x-code to device , how can debug

Answer (score 12):

It seems that `react-native log-ios` is not working anymore since RN .50 
You can use `react-native-log-ios` npm package instead

```
npm i -g react-native-log-ios
```

and then

```
react-native-log-ios <XCode Project Name>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you close the app on the device (so that XCode shows it as stopped) and then start the app again (through the device, not with XCode), the console logs will go to the terminal (assuming metro is running).

Of course, you don't get XCode debug logs, for my needs that's fine.