# Sometimes console.log shows in log-ios sometimes it doesn't

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have run `react-native start` in one terminal, and then `react-native ios-run` in another. My initial `console.log` rarely show, sometimes they do.

Lot's of times, randomly I do see:

> LOG MESSAGE QUOTA EXCEEDED - SOME MESSAGES FROM THIS PROCESS HAVE BEEN DISCARDED

Are my `console.log`'s being discarded? I tried clearing the console to see it more clearly but I can't find a way to clear console either.

On Android, I wouldn't have issue with missing `console.log`.

Comment: Try using `react-native-log-ios` npm pkg, same command than `react-native los-ios`, but working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

react-native logs information using syslog daemon. This daemon attempts to prevent spamming to the log (DoS attack). These limits are set on per process basis.

The simple solution is to stop/start simulator and you will be obtain new process that is not limited by the previous behaviour.

The other solution is to disable syslogd limits what will be heavilly depends on your operation system.

Comment: Thank you very much Marek for this, this is has been bugging for a long time. May you please add some steps on how to accomplish those solutions (especially the second one).

Comment: @Noitidart Which operation system are you interested in? On MacOSX it should be syslogd ... [-mps_limit quota]

Comment: thanks - I am on Windows 10 for Android dev. And then for mac i am on 1012.1 Sierra. I am very new to mac, just started in the last 2 months. I'm not sure what syslogd is :(

Comment: syslogd is a name of the application/daemon that brings together log information from various sources. Take a look at wikipedia or questions here. -- I can't help with Windows as I'm not using them for years.

Answer (score 1):

i found that the `JavascriptCore` engine won't automatically redirect the `console.log` to either `XCode output panel` or the system builtin `Console.App`， not to mention the self-broken `log-ios` command.

the only way to see console.log without remote debugging in browser is redirect(bind) it ourselves:

```
//Add this headers
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>
#import <jschelpers/JavaScriptCore. h>
#import <React/RCTBridge+Private.h>
...
...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  ...
  ...
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


  ::sleep(2); //<---!!!!!see below

  JSGlobalContextRef globalContext = rootView.bridge.jsContextRef;
  JSContext *context = [JSC_JSContext(globalContext) contextWithJSGlobalContextRef:globalContext];
  context[@"console"][@"log"] = ^(NSString *message) {
    NSLog(@"Javascript log: %@",message);
  };
  return YES;
}
```

**Caution:** the `JSContext` within `reactInstance` is created in another thread, I don't know how to get the loaded event(in only my project, since i don't like to modify the react-native engine), just wait sometime here for testing purpose.

Comment: Wow this is some deep thought. Thanks for sharing it!