# 'react-native log-ios' doesn't work

Tags: react-native

`react-native log-ios` doesn't work with xcode 9.1

I get this error:

> ```
> Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/Tom/App/node_modules (18ms)
> NOTE:  Most system logs have moved to a new logging system.  See log(1) for more information.
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) <Warning>: Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
> Nov  8 08:30:06 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService) <Warning>: Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
> Nov  8 08:30:08 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd[2968]) <Warning>: Service exited with abnormal code: 1
> Nov  8 08:30:08 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.WebBookmarks.webbookmarksd[2936]) <Warning>: Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: No such file or directory: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/webbookmarksd
> Nov  8 08:30:08 MacBook-Pro com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.CDC87161-72A2-478C-AC7A-328643D6B81C[2781] (com.apple.WebBookmarks.webbookmarksd[2936]) <Notice>: Service setup event to handle failure and will not launch until it fires.
> Nov  8 08:30:17 MacBook-Pro profiled[2920] <Error>: objc[2920]: Class SFUserNotification is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Sharing (0x10d4f2700) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices (0x12854f358). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> Nov  8 08:30:22 MacBook-Pro budd[2809] <Error>: objc[2809]: Class BYBuddyDaemonCloudSyncClient is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SetupAssistant.framework/SetupAssistant (0x109356930) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SetupAssistant.framework/budd (0x108e1e1f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> ```

Has anyone been able to find a workaround for this?

```
Environment:
  OS:  macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
  Node:  7.9.0
  Yarn:  0.27.5
  npm:  4.2.0
  Watchman:  4.7.0
  Xcode:  Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
  Android Studio:  Not Found

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: ^16.0.0 => 16.0.0
  react-native: ^0.50.0-rc.1 => 0.50.0-rc.1
```

Comment: XCode is on v9.2 now. Maybe try upgrading and see if it is still broken

Comment: XCode 9.2 also gives the same error

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @rptwsthi no.  :( . If you find one, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Today it started working own it's own. I did nothing. Except for shuttin down system and starting back today. Then I launched terminal first ran 'react-native run-ios', opened another tab and executed 'react-native log-ios'.

Comment: see my answer in another similar post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884984/4049216)

Comment: Try out [react-native-log-ios](https://github.com/Annihil/react-native-log-ios) npm pkg, it works without remote JS debugging, out of the box.

Comment: Try one of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40031187/936098 Option #3 worked for me.